# NSSwitchButton alternatives

Tags: cocoa, word-wrap, nsbutton

I am writing a Mac application that provides a "test" like function.  This application (through a connection with a server).  Basically the application will give the students a story to read, followed by a series of questions (also from the server) where the user can (attempt) to select the correct answers, and send the result back to the server to be verified.

Implementing the "story" part was easy.  Just send all of the text to a NSTextView.  I had been planning to implement the "select your answer" as programmatically created NSSwitchButtons.  However, some of the possible answers might take up more than one line.  I have not been able get (any) NSButton class to wrap text based on the frame size, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to override NSButtonCell to allow the text to wrap.

What other Cocoa class(es) should I use to accomplish this task?  I need to have a check-box interface (so that people can select one or more possible answers, and the answers can be an arbitrary length - within reason!)  Ideally it would also be easy to use so that it will be easy to programatically layout the answers as well.  (Some problems may only have 2 choices, while others may have 5+)  I can't imagine I'm the only one who needs this type of functionality

(Oh...since a picture is worth 1,000 words, I've attached a screen-shot of my app below with some answer text running off of the screen)

[image: Screenshot of app]

Comment: Oh...in researching the NSButton's reasons for not wrapping, it was clear that the reason it doesn't wrap is because Apple wants to encourage developers to make short, concise button names for the action, and not long, rambling button names.  However, this scenario is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSButton` will respect explicit linefeed characters embedded in the text, but I suppose that would not meet your needs.  An alternative would be to have a static text item next to a checkbox with no title.  Of course, if you want to be able to toggle the checkbox by clicking the text, you would have a little more programming to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It looks like I need to do a little more programming.  I'm thinking that your empty checkbox next to a text item might be my best option...